# htaccess redirecting to files available in the public directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**[ Background ]**
This is the structure to my application:

```
app/
    controllers/
        ...
    modules/
        ...
    views/
        ...
public/
    css/
        main.css
    images/
        ...
    js/
        ...
    index.php 
.htaccess
```

For various reasons (security, organization, etc.) the public application (website) is loaded and displayed by `public/index.php` At the "root" of my server I have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /BU/cs-602/developer-story/
    RewriteRule ^(\/||index\.*)$ public/index.php [L,QSA]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RedirectMatch ^(/BU/cs-602/developer-story.)([\w\d\s\/\-\:\_%\ ]*\.css)$ $1public/$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([\w\d\-\_\/\ ]*)$ public/index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

These rules should rewrite/ redirect all requests from the server "root" to `public/index.php` Since I am developing locally on my development server this project is not actually at the root of my server but is located at `/BU/cs-602/developer-story/` This is why I added the `RewriteBase` rule.

If I remove the `RedirectMatch` rule everything from an MVC standpoint works:

URLs like `http://localhost/BU/cs-602/developer-story` or `http://localhost/BU/cs-602/developer-story/` become `http://localhost/BU/cs-602/developer-story/public/index.php` AND URLs like `http://localhost/BU/cs-602/developer-story/user/id` become `http://localhost/BU/cs-602/developer-story/public/index.php?p=user/id`.

Here is a live [htaccess test](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=527134f1-627e-4f25-9aae-05b839f476fd).

**[ Question ]**
How can I fix the `.htaccess` file or the `RedirectMatch` rule to redirect request to resources like `CSS` or `JS` files? The current rule works in the [tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=527134f1-627e-4f25-9aae-05b839f476fd) but not on my server unless I remove the `RedirectMatch` rule.

I would like a URL like `http://localhost/BU/cs-602/developer-story/css/main.css` to become `http://localhost/BU/cs-602/developer-story/public/css/main.css` that way in my HTML I do something like:

```html
<img src="images/logo.png">
```

The server actually loads:

```html
<img src="public/images/logo.png">
```

This way I do not have to prefix all my resources with `public/`.

**[ Disclosure ]**
This question is for help with a final project at my University, but this type question is allowed and not violating academic policies. Making a project with `htaccess` and `MVC` is not a requirement, just something I'm doing to challenge myself.

**UPDATE:**
Here is my original `RedirectMacth` rule. Anything that is not a PHP or HTML file is redirected:

```
RedirectMatch ([\w\d\s\/\-\:\_%\ ]*\.(?!php|htm|html)) $1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after reviewing the error logs on my server. My various attempts were causing redirect loops. Here is my working `.htaccess` file in case it helps anyone trying to do something similar.

The key is to short circuit the `.htaccess` file when necessary so it doesn't keep rewriting your URLs infinitely. I added inline comments to explain the process:

```sh
# Redirect all requests to the public directory.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Only needing for local develoment in my case.
    RewriteBase /BU/cs-602/developer-story/
    # If nothing or an index page is requested go to `public/index.php` and stop processing.
    RewriteRule ^(\/||.*index\..*)$ public/index.php [L,QSA]
    # If the URL already contains the `public/` directory go to URL and stop processing.
    RewriteRule ^(.*public\/.*)$ $1 [L,QSA]
    # If it appears this URL is for a resource (JS, CSS, etc.) prefix with `public/`.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([\w\d\s\-\_\/\%]*)\.(?!php|htm|html).*$
    # Go to the modified URL if the last rule triggered and stop processing.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    # Rewrite all remaing URLs to our apps MVC structure.
    RewriteRule ^([\w\d\s\-\_\/\%]*)$ public/index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```